# Joining two different types of collections and removing duplicates

Tags: c#

I am currently working on an MVC app during my internship. It will be an app where you create reports about sold products. Products are listed with check-boxes, there is no possibility to add any new for user. If I open a new report window I need a full list of not checked products (product in a model has just an ID and name) which will happen without any issues because the collection in a **reportModel** is empty at this stage. I got stuck on a problem that in the same window by the same controller I will be opening an existing report for edition.

I have two separate models for products: **Products** and **ProductsInReport** and also Models for their collections, further come their **ViewModels**.
In case of editing existing report I want to have displayed checked Products from previous edition (creating) of the report but also the rest of products without duplication. And that is where is my issue. I don't know how to filter this.

**Controller** calls procedure which gets report and in it we have collection of products(that were checked, can be null). It also calls the second procedure which gets collection of all available products from the DB. 
I was trying to work with these ways:
http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c

But I have troubles there since my collections have different types.
The question is how on the level of **ViewModel** can I compare products that came with report with all products available to get result with no duplicates?

I hope I made myself possibly clear (if not I am sorry, second day of working with the same little problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While they may be (possibly incorrectly) different types, there should be something common between the two types, most like an ID, eg `ProductID`.

You should be able to use this to remove the used products from the full list to give the available list.

```
var usedProductIDs = report.Products.Select(x=>x.ProductID).ToList();
var availableProducts = allProducts.Where(x=>!usedProductIDs.Contains(x.ProductInReportID))
                                   .ToList();
```

(there are no doubt more efficient ways to achieve the same, but this is the essential idea).

To help further would need further details of your objects and properties.